# Empty space of 1 pixel above UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview

In the landscape orientation I can "see through" one pixel of the view behind (the split view controller, visible between the status bar and the navigation bar):

[image: 1 pixel]

I rechecked the width, the height and the autoresize parameters of the top-most view with the navigation bar, however I cannot understand where does the gap come from.

Comment: It's hard for me to see what you are talking about in the image you attached.  Could you change the background tinting or color scheme so it's more apparent in your updated screenshot?

Comment: Does this occur when running the application on the device or in the simulator? Or both?

Comment: Since iOS5.0 automatic frame update calculation on orientation change has changed. I have a problem like this, on orientation change, my view frame was updated with this values (0.0, 268.0,  480.0, 32.0) on iOS4.2 and with this values (0.0, 268.0, 480.0, 31.0) on iOS5.0. So your 'one pixel bug' can come from this new behavior.