# Custom UINavigationBar is offset by 1 pixel at the top

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have a subclassed UINavigationBar where I'm overriding drawRect to provide a png with transparency as a background.  Every thing works as expected, save for a 1 pixel space at the top of the bar (I can see the underlying map moving in the space).

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g34SQ.png)

Only thing I was able to find is this question which sounds like my problem but I don't know what to make of the explanation: [Empty space of 1 pixel above UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818982/empty-space-of-1-pixel-above-uinavigationbar)

I have verified that the PNG file does not have 1 pixel of transparency at the top of the image.
Overriding in subclassed UINavigationBar:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 

[_bg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _bg.size.width, _bg.size.height)];
// showing correct bounds - drawRect: 0.000000, 0.000000, 320.000000, 85.000000
NSLog(@"drawRect: %f, %f, %f, %f",  rect.origin.x, 
                                    rect.origin.y, 
                                    rect.size.width, 
                                    rect.size.height);
```

}

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, _bg.size.height);
NSLog(@"sizefits");
return sz;
```

}

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you use a 24/32bit png image or an 8bit one?

Comment: Hi He, thanks for the response. I double verified, and it is 32-bit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my custom nav bar, although I was using UIAppearance proxies to set a custom background image instead of overriding drawRect:. This was my quick fix, in viewWillAppear: on the root view controller:

```
// Make sure nav bar is flush with status bar (iOS 5 iPhone portrait somehow gives status bar height 20 and nav bar y 20.5, so we miss a pixel).
CGRect navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
navBarFrame.origin.y = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = navBarFrame;
```